# What kind of Android service should I use for XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, android-service

I have an XMPP server for which I am using asmack. I have used that in an android app but not as a service. As a result when I close the app, the client gets disconnected from the server. Which Android service should I use to that connection always persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement you own class extending the Service base class of the android framework. There is plenty of documentation on developer.android.com and here. But be aware that if you implement the service so it runs always in the background you have to use AIDL interfaces to comunicate with it. It is a bit strange at first, but doable.
Also note that with great power comes great responsibility. So you are starting your service which always runs in the background. Certainly you will start using WakeLocks to ensure that more complex (longer) XMPP packets are written completey before the device goes to sleep. But be responsible about it. It is very very easy to be burden to battery life. 
It can also be worth to look at C2DM for Android. In most cases this coupled with some HTTP-Requests is a better choice than implementing your own XMPP background service.